# JSONPATH filter can't match values

Tags: json, jsonpath

Hi I'm trying to filter some oids based on values. For instance: I would like to return OID with value less than 1000

```
[
    {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "607f24106f097b42ba7dea5e"
    },
    "SNMP_ONTOLOGIA": {
      "oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.1.2.2.20.6.3.1.10",
      "value": 833
    },
    "contextData": {
      "deviceTemplate": null,
      "device": null,
      "clientConnection": null,
      "clientSession": null,
      "user": "administrator",
      "timezoneId": "UTC",
      "timestamp": "2021-04-20T18:57:20Z",
      "timestampMillis": 1618945040731,
      "source": "FLOWENGINE"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "607f2f576f097b42ba7dea62"
    },
    "SNMP_ONTOLOGIA": {
      "oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.100.1.1.30.12",
      "value": 25505
    },
    "contextData": {
      "deviceTemplate": null,
      "device": null,
      "clientConnection": null,
      "clientSession": null,
      "user": "administrator",
      "timezoneId": "UTC",
      "timestamp": "2021-04-20T19:45:27Z",
      "timestampMillis": 1618947927982,
      "source": "FLOWENGINE"
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried in https://jsonpath.com/ these syntaxes:

> $..SNMP_ONTOLOGIA[?(@.value < 1000)]
>
> $..SNMP_ONTOLOGIA[?(@.value < 1000)].oid

I don't understand why for the book example it works and for the example above no.

link https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#examples

Syntax

> $..book[?(@.price > 4)]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate someone who could explain me a little more how it worked. But I managed it as this:

```
> jp.query(SNMP, '$..[?(@.value > 10)]');
[
  { oid: '1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.1.2.2.20.6.3.1.10', value: 833 },
  { oid: '1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.100.1.1.30.12', value: 25505 }
]
>
>
> jp.query(SNMP, '$..[?(@.value < 1000)]');
[ { oid: '1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.1.2.2.20.6.3.1.10', value: 833 } ]
> jp.query(SNMP, '$..[?(@.value < 1000)].oid');
[ '1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.1.2.2.20.6.3.1.10' ]
```

ps: using require('jsonpath') npm package

ps2: for OID as said initially

```
jp.query(SNMP, '$..[?(@.oid == \'1.3.6.1.4.1.6527.6.1.2.2.20.6.3.1.10\')].value');
[ 833 ]
```